# jQuery: table with grouping and sum in group footer/header?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery-solution which enables sorting and grouping by columns; then, in the footer section, it should be possible to show the sum of all values above.

Example: I've got three columns: Country, Date and Sales:

```
US     20120714       50
DE     20120714       40
BR     20120714       30
US     20120715       60
DE     20120715       60
BR     20120715       20
```

If I sort by country:

```
BR     20120714       30
BR     20120715       20
                      50
DE     20120714       40
DE     20120715       60
                     100
US     20120714       50
US     20120715       60
                     110
```

If I sort by date:

```
BR     20120714       30
DE     20120714       40
US     20120714       50
                     120
BR     20120715       20
DE     20120715       60
US     20120715       60
                     140
```

and so on...

Is there a plugin available for this?

Comment: why downvoting and vote for close? didn't know I was violating something :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already suggested, Datatables is a nice and easy-to-use JQuery plugin fitting your needs. It supports sorting out of the box, and also grouping can be done. See this [example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html).
You can also modify the footer to show the sum of a column, like in this [example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html).

You can, however, also use the `fnDrawCallback` function. It is called every time your table is drawn and offers you the possibility to modify HOW it should be drawn.

Example:

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
    // Get all rows of your table
    var nTrs = $tableElement.find('tbody tr');
    // Enumerate all rows
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nTrs.length; i++) {
         var iDisplayIndex = oSettings._iDisplayStart + i;
         var dataIndex = oSettings.aiDisplay[iDisplayIndex];
         sum += oSettings.aoData[dataIndex]._aData.{your item};
    }
    // Insert sum at the end
    $tableElement.find(' tbody tr:last').after('<p>'+sum+'</p>');
```

In this example, the variable `$tableElement` contains the JQuery object for your datatable instance.

Answer (score 1):

Its clear you need to try serach, its very easy to use Google, here you need to try by yourself then you need to ask your question about your "problem".

Here you have to learn how to fishing not to give you a free fishs :)

Another side of your question is very wide, I mean many will give you many plugins, and all are correct, but you will select "your" answer as "you" want, not because that answer is really correct or the best.

So that why you will get votes down. **(as what I think or I see)**

Anyway, you can see if you want plugin like that look at : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/plug-ins/sorting_sType.html

or another ways : http://datatables.net/
maybe you need to code (summation).

and here alot of plugins : http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-amazing-jquery-tables/#.UAUUD_XU6Iw

explorer them by yourself I hope you will get something helpful, I got these links with very easy Googling and with silly words :)

Comment: thanks for your kind response, BUT :) => I also found those links, but they are not providing the sum-functionality in the footer - therefore my question. Second: in SO, there are a lot of "does any XY exist"-question, if it's not trivial to find the solution - as in my case. And third: if I vote a question down, I leave a comment with the reason.

Comment: I didnt make a vote down for you, and like what you said, usually I leave my comment :), now but about your comment, look, that impossible to find something like what you want exactly, sure you want to make some customization, choose best plugin and customize it, if you failed but you believe you can do what you tring to do, ask your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather not hog the client with heavy logic, it'll stutter and be slow.

Just perform all the sorting/grouping/counting *server* side and provide your client with all the data already processed and ready to show.

For this you just need a trivial ajax call and a bunch of parameters: no need to do magic where it's not needed.